# have vim tag-matchlist open a new tab

Tags: vim

I've got things configured so `CTRL-]` on a tag goes directly to the file in a new tab if there is only one match.  If there are multiple matches, tag-matchlist appears in a new pane in the present tab.  Hitting the number and enter then opens the entry in a split pane.

How can I adjust things, please, so that either:

a) the tab-matchlist opens in a new tab

or

b) the chosen entry will appear in a new tab

Comment: How have you configured `CTRL-]` so far?  By the matchlist, do you mean the list described under `:help tag-matchlist` and displayed with `:tselect`, or is it something provided by a plugin?

Comment: In my .vimrc: `nnoremap <C-]> <C-w><C-]><C-w>T`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out how to do exactly what I want:

`nnoremap <C-]> :tab tjump <C-r><C-w><CR>`

If there's one match, that jumps directly to the tag in a new tab.

If there are multiple matches, that opens the tag-matchlist, then once the desired entry is selected, it jumps to that tag in a new tab.

Many thanks to @romainl for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following mapping to show the matchlist for the tag under your cursor in the current window and open the chosen tag in a tab:

```
nnoremap <F6> :tab tselect <C-r><C-w><CR>
```

It is an alternative version of your mapping but a little less messy.

The following mapping yanks the tag under your cursor to register `t`, opens a new tab and does `:tselect` with register `t` (and thus shows the matchlist in that tab):

```
nnoremap <F7> "tyiw:tabnew<CR>:tselect <C-r>t<CR>
```

Comment: No reason except that I tested that command in 2 or 3 tries and forgot the `<bar>` at some point.

Comment: The first option was close to what I wanted.  Switching `tselect` to `tjump` and the `F6` to `<C-]>` made it work.  The second option chokes due to opening a new tab that lacks the context to the tags file.

Comment: You should get into the habit of starting Vim from the root dir of your project.

Comment: I generally do.  But I use the Fugitive / Ctags for SVN way, storing the tags file in the .git / .svn directory.